How can I make a custom template for prevention of screenshot on the screen in flutter?
I have tried the basic prevention of screenshot on the page which given a basic black image, but I want to customise it like whatsapp does.
Can we do it in flutter ?
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_windowmanager/flutter_windowmanager.dart';

class SecureScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<SecureScreen> createState() => _SecureScreenState();
}

class _SecureScreenState extends State<SecureScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _enableScreenshotPrevention();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _disableScreenshotPrevention();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> _enableScreenshotPrevention() async {
    await FlutterWindowManager.addFlags(FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);
  }

  Future<void> _disableScreenshotPrevention() async {
    await FlutterWindowManager.clearFlags(FlutterWindowManager.FLAG_SECURE);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Secure Screen")),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text("Screenshot prevention is active on this screen."),
      ),
    );
  }
}



Custom Template for Preventing Screenshots in Flutter
Use no_screenshot plugin, listen for screenshot events, and display a custom widget as a response.

Prerequisites

Add the no_screenshot plugin to your project by including it in your pubspec.yaml file:

no_screenshot: ^0.3.1


Run flutter pub get to install the package.


Steps
1️⃣ Disable Screenshots
You can disable screenshots and screen recordings by creating an instance of NoScreenshot and invoking the screenshotOff() method.
import 'package:no_screenshot/no_screenshot.dart';

final _noScreenshot = NoScreenshot.instance;

void disableScreenshot() async {
  bool result = await _noScreenshot.screenshotOff();
  debugPrint('Screenshot Disabled: $result');
}

2️⃣ Enable Screenshot Listening
Enable listening for screenshot activities by starting the screenshot listener.
void startScreenshotListening() async {
  await _noScreenshot.startScreenshotListening();
}

3️⃣ React to Screenshot Events
Set up a stream to listen for screenshot events and show a custom widget when a screenshot is detected.
void listenForScreenshot() {
  _noScreenshot.screenshotStream.listen((event) {
    if (event.wasScreenshotTaken) {
      showCustomAlert(event.screenshotPath);
    }
  });
}

void showCustomAlert(String path) {
  // Customize your alert widget here
  print('Screenshot detected at path: $path');
}

4️⃣ Integrate into Application
Here’s a full example that combines these steps:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:no_screenshot/no_screenshot.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const PreventScreenshotApp());
}

class PreventScreenshotApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const PreventScreenshotApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: PreventScreenshotPage(),
    );
  }
}

class PreventScreenshotPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PreventScreenshotPageState createState() => _PreventScreenshotPageState();
}

class _PreventScreenshotPageState extends State<PreventScreenshotPage> {
  final _noScreenshot = NoScreenshot.instance;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startScreenshotListening();
    listenForScreenshot();
  }

  void startScreenshotListening() async {
    await _noScreenshot.startScreenshotListening();
  }

  void listenForScreenshot() {
    _noScreenshot.screenshotStream.listen((event) {
      if (event.wasScreenshotTaken) {
        showCustomAlert();
      }
    });
  }

  void showCustomAlert() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return Dialog(
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                const Icon(
                  Icons.warning_amber_outlined,
                  size: 80,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                const Text(
                  "Screenshot detected",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                  child: const Text("Dismiss"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("Prevent Screenshots")),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: disableScreenshot,
          child: const Text("Disable Screenshot"),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void disableScreenshot() async {
    bool result = await _noScreenshot.screenshotOff();
    debugPrint('Screenshot Disabled: $result');
  }
}


Summary
By combining the no_screenshot plugin and listening for screenshot events, you can create a robust solution to detect and react to screenshots in your Flutter app. Customize the showCustomAlert method to display any widget that fits your application's requirements.
